# Time not graphing on Form chart

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to graph some data with TimeDate as the X axis. I set the XValueType in the series to Time and set scaleview with this

```
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
```

I can graph data with DateTime.Now

```
chart1.Series["Change"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToOADate(), data);
```

But when I try to get the DateTime from text it will not graph

```
String s = "11/4/2014_18:36";
DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MM/d/yyyy_HH:mm", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out timeStamp);
chart1.Series["Change"].Points.AddXY(timeStamp, data);
```

There is just a big red X and no errors are given.

Comment: What kind of chart is this? Silverlight? WPF?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Windows form application

Comment: @JohnSaunders Windows forms is not WPF...

Comment: Could have sworn he said WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `DateTime.Now` to the chart you use `ToADate` which returns a `double`.  When you parse the date string you then try to add the resulting DateTime as a point on the chart. If you want the equivalent functionality, you need to convert the parsed date like you did with the first:

```
String s = "11/4/2014_18:36";
DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MM/d/yyyy_HH:mm", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out timeStamp);
chart1.Series["Change"].Points.AddXY(timestamp.ToADate(), data);
```